# Is CNN shift invariant?

Tags: conv-neural-network

I have seen multiple resources on the web says that CNN *is* or *is not* shift invariant. I do think that CNN is shift invariant as the convolution kernel will scan the image to detect the features that it matches, however this [paper](https://richzhang.github.io/antialiased-cnns/) shows empirical result that this is not the case. This [answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/121703/what-does-shift-invariant-mean-in-convolutional-neural-network) says that CNN is locally shift invariant but it can tolerate large shifts. Also, these [slides](https://cedar.buffalo.edu/%7Esrihari/CSE676/9.12%20CapsuleNets.pdf) (slide 6) say that if you shuffle face parts like eyes and noise in an image, CNN still classify the image as a face. This means that it is shift invariant.

So, what is the correct answer? What is the thing that I did not get from the slides mentioned above?